# Kafka starting error in CentOS

Tags: confluent-platform

### Kafka server failed to start on confluent start command.

### command lines:

```
~]# sudo confluent start

zookeeper is already running. Try restarting if needed
```

Starting kafka

```
-Kafka failed to start

kafka is [DOWN]

Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
confluent log kafka
```

to see the log from Kafka trying to start, and see what the error is.